# Rails duplicated the parameters inside the resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-resource

I am using the Angular Resource and I don't understand why Rails duplicated the parameters and put it inside the resource name. I just need to understand why this is happening.

```
// post data
{"title":"asdsad"}

// rails parameters 
Parameters: {"title"=>"asdsad", "presentation"=>{"title"=>"asdsad"}}
```

Duplicate because welcome to Stackoverflow where you need 50 points to comments so this happen. I really so sorry: [AngularJS $resource sending out an extra "registration" hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442474/angularjs-resource-sending-out-an-extra-registration-hash)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> ..if you've turned on config.wrap_parameters in your initializer [check the file
>   config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb] or [you] are calling
>   wrap_parameters() in your controller...the parameters will be cloned and
>   wrapped in the key according to your controller's name by default.
>
> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

In other words, what you are seeing is the default way rails enters things in the params hash.

Comment: Just had the same issue, calling `wrap_parameters false` in the controller will also stop the behaviour on a controller specific level

Comment: @doz87 that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question but I hadn't understood the problem and needed a different solution.

In my passwords controller (for enabling password reset via email), my parameters looked like this:

`{"email"=>"eg@eg.com", "code"=>"123", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>{"email"=>"eg@eg.com", "code"=>"123", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}`

I thought, "why are my params duplicated inside of `password`", not realizing that the outer `password` was coming from the resource name. (Thanks, 7stud!) But if I added `wrap_parameters false` at the top of my controller to flatten out the params, then I couldn't use the 'require/permit' pattern for strong params:

```
#passwords_controller.rb
...
private
def forgot_password_params
    params.require(:password).permit(:email, :password, :code)
end
```

To make this more legible, I used `wrap_parameters` to *rename* the outer password ref in the params. The code:

```
#passwords_controller.rb
wrap_parameters "reset" 
...
private
def forgot_password_params
    params.require(:reset).permit(:email, :password, :code)
end
```

and the resulting params: `{"email"=>"eg@eg.com", "code"=>"123", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset"=>{"email"=>"eg@eg.com", "code"=>"123", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}`

I then immediately ran into a related issue where for an in-app password reset, I passed in `newPassword` from my form but it was not in my params. By default, params only include attributes from the model. `wrap_parameters` let me fix this as well:

```
#users_controller.rb
wrap_parameters :user, include: [:username, :email, :password, :newPassword]
```